# "Maximum request length exceeded" error handling only working for large files

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to handle the "Maximum request length exceeded" error after an ajax request, it works fine for really large files, but for smaller files the error response is lost so I can't handle it the way I want to. This is the relevant code:

```
    $(document).on({
        ajaxError: function (event, request, settings) {
            console.log("error Ajax error");
            console.log(event);
            console.log(request);
            console.log(settings);
            if(request.responseText.contains("Maximum request length exceeded")){
                alert("Error! max file size: " + "@HttpContext.Current.Session["MaxFileSize"]");
            }
        }
    });
```

For files above 150Mb or so in size it works, the responseText is the html error page, everything runs as I want to. But for smaller files the responseText is empty. I've tried to configure the maxRequestLength in the web.config with 20Mb and 100Mb, the behavior is the same.

When I breakpoint in my application_error I can see that indeed the error happened and it was a "Max Request Exceeded" error, but if I try to modify the Response it does not work, again, for smaller files, for really large files it works fine, here is my example code:

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lastException = Server.GetLastError();

        var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        logger.Fatal(lastException);

        if (lastException.Message.Contains("Maximum request length exceeded"))
        {
            this.Server.ClearError();
            HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
            Response.Write(
                new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                    new { error = "MaxLength Error Occured, handle in page" }
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

One thing I noticed is that when the responseText is lost application_error is called twice, which I'm not sure if its relevant.

I've been searching all over and I haven't found any solution, most people's problem is that the error happens even after configuring it correctly, my problem is not that it happens when it shouldn't, it happens when it should but I can't handle it because the error's responseText is lost. I would greatly appreciate any directions to solve this issue.

Update: I had not tried a different browser, I was doing it all in Firefox, I have tried it now in Chrome and IE and it doesn't work no matter the file size, the responseText of the request object is always empty. Application_Error is called only once though, in Firefox is called twice, and with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to close the question. I finally figured it out. The problem is when debugging in Visual Studio, I guess the server behaves differently, once I published in our test environment the error behaved as I expected it, and worked with any file above the limit I configured.